# Server getting error after doing distro upgrade: tg3_stop_block timed out

Tags: server, ethernet

im running ubuntu on a HP Server Blade ProLiant BL25p G1

after doing distro upgrade to oneiric im geting dpammed whit these messages on terminal.

[image: terminal login]

if i turn of the eth0 interface with sudo ifconfig eth0 downi can se what i write.

this is what is at end of my dmesg

[image]

and if i start in recovery mode i get this message

[image]

if i reboot the mashine in older kernel it works just fine, any suggjestion how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not to state the obvious, but looks like a kernel bug. There are similar reports in launchpad, bugzilla, arch ...

Ubuntu (most recent) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/545334

It seems to come up with a variety of network cards, and I did not find a solution.

Probably the most helpful bug report was here, on Arch

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/19369

No solution for you , but a nice list of the various bug reports across the various distros.

I would advise you file a bug report with kernel.org

http://bugzilla.kernel.org/

for kernel.org guidelines see :

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/reporting_code_bugs.html

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lkml/reporting-bugs.html

In the meantime continue to use the older kernel and see if the next kernel fixes the bug.

Comment: I've also just seen this when going from CentOS 6.1 to 6.2 on a HP BL25p blade.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen you were right - check the bug reports but the bug listed is a different one.  Look here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1005699  at item #24

Answer (score 0):

In the Launchpad Bug reports https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1005699, see item #24 for the fix. The discussion talks about a tigon3 driver problem in the kernel.  The 3.0.24 and below tree had this error but as Ubuntu now has support for a 3.0.25-40 kernel the bug has been fixed.  Item #20 talks the details of how this problem was discovered by working back from the development kernels 3.4, 3.3, and 3.2 and how it was discovered what the tg3_stop_block_error means.  It is a problem with TSO. TSO stands for TCP Segmentation offload.

What happened in the pre 3.0.25 kernel is explained by [Matt Carlson](http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/Precise-Patch-0-1-tg3-Fix-TSO-CAP-for-5704-devs-w-ASF-enabled-td4978544.html) here

> On the earliest TSO capable devices, TSO was accomplished through 
>   firmware.  The TSO cannot coexist with ASF management firmware though. 
>   The tg3 driver determines whether or not ASF is enabled by calling 
>   tg3_get_eeprom_hw_cfg(), which checks a particular bit of NIC memory. 
>   Commit dabc5c670d3f86d15ee4f42ab38ec5bd2682487d, entitled "tg3: Move 
>   TSO_CAPABLE assignment", accidentally moved the code that determines 
>   TSO capabilities earlier than the call to tg3_get_eeprom_hw_cfg().  As a 
>   consequence, the driver was attempting to determine TSO capabilities 
>   before it had all the data it needed to make the decision. This patch fixes the problem by revisiting and reevaluating the decision 
>   after tg3_get_eeprom_hw_cfg() is called.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade should do the trick.