# Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe driver tg3 will not install?

Tags: installation, drivers, broadcom

```
aries@aries-laptop:~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
aries@aries-laptop:~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1705]
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc Device [1002:9641]
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: ATI Technologies Inc Device [1002:1714]
00:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1709]
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:170b]
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7800] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:780b] (rev 13)
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:780d] (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:780e] (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:780f] (rev 40)
00:16.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:16.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1700] (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1701]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1702]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1703]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1704]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1718]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1716]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device [1022:1719]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
01:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
01:00.2 System peripheral [0880]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16be] (rev 10)
01:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16bf] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4358]
```

Comment: This isn't really solvable without more information. What have you tried so far? Are there any other details you can give? (eg, look for interesting lines in dmesg, check for other ethernet devices with `ip link show`, check for interesting modules in `lsmod`)

Comment: I think this question has the same answer as this question:[link] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/88319/server-getting-error-after-doing-distro-upgrade-tg3-stop-block-timed-out/154864#154864) because the issue is a kernel issue

Answer (score 1):

In the Launchpad Bug reports https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1005699, see item #24 for the fix. The discussion talks about a tigon3 (broadcom) driver problem in the kernel.  The 3.0.24 and below tree had this error but as Ubuntu now has support for a 3.0.25-40 kernel the bug has been fixed.  Item #20 talks the details of how this problem was discovered by working back from the development kernels 3.4, 3.3, and 3.2 and how it was discovered what the tg3_stop_block_error means.  It is a problem with TSO. TSO stands for TCP Segmentation offload.

Ubuntu 12.04 (Non LTS) came with a kernel older than 3.0.25.

What happened in the pre 3.0.25 kernel is explained by [Matt Carlson](http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/Precise-Patch-0-1-tg3-Fix-TSO-CAP-for-5704-devs-w-ASF-enabled-td4978544.html) here

> On the earliest TSO capable devices, TSO was accomplished through 
>   firmware.  The TSO cannot coexist with ASF management firmware though. 
>   The tg3 driver determines whether or not ASF is enabled by calling 
>   tg3_get_eeprom_hw_cfg(), which checks a particular bit of NIC memory. 
>   Commit dabc5c670d3f86d15ee4f42ab38ec5bd2682487d, entitled "tg3: Move 
>   TSO_CAPABLE assignment", accidentally moved the code that determines 
>   TSO capabilities earlier than the call to tg3_get_eeprom_hw_cfg().  As a 
>   consequence, the driver was attempting to determine TSO capabilities 
>   before it had all the data it needed to make the decision. This patch fixes the problem by revisiting and reevaluating the decision 
>   after tg3_get_eeprom_hw_cfg() is called.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade should do the trick because it will install a newer kernel including the drivers required to solve this problem.